# Powerpoint Chart Data Update From Excel Instance - Data disappears when Edit Data

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am editing a PPT template with data from Excel using the following code:

```
    Set shapeObject = oPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideIndex).Shapes("Chart 9")
    With shapeObject.Chart.ChartData
     .Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Value = Sheets(slideSheetName).Range("D3").Text
     .Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Value = Sheets(slideSheetName).Range("D4").Text
     .Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4").Value = Sheets(slideSheetName).Range("D5").Text
     .Workbook.Close
    End With
```

When I click to Edit Data on the chart in PPT I see the data as it was copied over from the above code.  But some users see no data in the Edit Data sheet but the chart itself still has data in it.

Has anyone ever seen that before?  What is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
.Workbook.Worksheets(1).
```

This reference doesn't seem sound.

I'd try something like this:

```
Workbooks('NameofWB').Sheets('Sheet1')
```

So the code is explicit as to what workbook is referenced.